# Find records which has all ids in pivot table in another table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

In my laravel project I have tables shown as below.

`groups` and `users` are in Many-to-Many relationship, which mean that a user can belongs to multiple groups.

The `group_user` table is intermediate table which represents which user belongs to which group.

`slot_votes` table records users' vote on slot. Relationship of it with `groups` table is `groups` table hasMany `slot_votes`.

`groups` table

```
|id | channel_id   |
+---+---------+
|1  |  U124  |
|2  |  U123  |
|3  |  U125  |
|4  |  U127  |
```

`users` table

```
|id | name   |
+---+---------+
|1  |  A  |
|2  |  B  |
|3  |  C  |
|4  |  D  |
```

`group_user` table

```
|id | group_id | user_id   |
+---+----------+-----------+
|1  |     1    |     1     |
|2  |     2    |     1     |
|3  |     2    |     2     |
|4  |     3    |     3     |
|5  |     4    |     3     |
|6  |     1    |     4     |
```

`slot_vote` table

```
|id | user_id | group_id  |    slot   |
+---+---------+-----------+-----------+
|1  |     1   |     1     |     A     |
|2  |     2   |     1     |     B     |
|3  |     2   |     2     |     C     |
|1  |     1   |     4     |     C     |
```

My question is how can I use Laravel Eloquent to get the group ids which has all its members voted?

For example, if group 1's members is `$userId = [1, 4]` and both of user 1 and 4 has voted (therefore exists in slot_votes table), I want to get group 1 id in the result.

What I have tried:

```
    Group::whereHas('users', function ($query, $votedUser) {
        $query->whereIn(
            'id',
            SlotVote::where('group_id', $groupId)->pluck('user_id')->unique()
        );
    }, '=', count($votedUser))->get();
```

But I couldn't figure out how to get `$groupId` in `whereIn` clause. Also, I am concerned of the query performance. Any idea on how can I get the results I need?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If you're concerned about performances and whant to do it all in one query I would suggest using leftJoin() starting off the Group model. Join the `group_user` and the `slot_vote` and compare the two counts: `COUNT(group_user.user_id)` and `COUNT(slot_vote.user_id)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will try it now.
Do you have any idea of how to do it using more than one query?

Comment: How about sub select?

Comment: With two query you can get number of user on each group with a SELECT COUNT(user_id) on `group_user` table and a GROUP BY group_id. And another query doing the same on the `slot_vote` table then compare for each group_id the counted users of both queries. But doing so and performing PHP search on collection of results is WAY less performant than doing so in one query with JOINs

Comment: @ZarkDev I am also wondering is there any way to do using Eloquent ORM? Is it better to use ORM instead of query builder in this case?

Comment: @ZarkDev sorry for multiple replies at once. I am trying your way of Joining and comparing counts. However I couldn't figure out how to compare count after joining tables. Could you provide code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the following code:

```
Group::leftJoin('group_user', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
                    ->leftJoin('slot_votes', 'group_user.user_id', '=', 'slot_votes.user_id')
                    ->selectRaw(
                        "groups.id, channel_id,
                        count(distinct group_user.user_id) as members,
                        count(distinct slot_votes.user_id) as voted_members",
                    )
                    ->groupBy('groups.id')
                    ->havingRaw('members=voted_members')
                    ->get();
```